# Confluent Schema Registry Cluster Mode

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka Connect from Confluent to consume Kafka stream and write to HDFS in parquet format. I am using Schema Registry service in 1 node and it is running fine. Now I want to distribute Schema Registry to cluster mode to handle fail over. Any link or snippet on how to achieve that will be very useful.

Answer (score 6):

It is hard to find, but we covered this architecture in our documentation:
http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/deployment.html#multi-dc-setup

To quote from the docs a bit (although you should read the docs, lots of good architecture advice and a recovery runbook are included):

> Assuming you have Schema Registry running, here are the recommended
>   steps to add Schema Registry instances in a new “slave” datacenter
>   (call it DC B):
>
> In DC B, make sure Kafka has unclean.leader.election.enable set to
>   false. In Kafka in DC B, create the _schemas topic. It should have 1
>   partition, kafkastore.topic.replication.factor of 3, and
>   min.insync.replicas at least 2. In DC B, run MirrorMaker with Kafka in
>   the “master” datacenter as the source and Kafka in DC B as the target.
>   In the Schema Registry config files in DC B, set
>   kafkastore.connection.url and schema.registry.zk.namespace to match
>   the instances already running, and set master.eligibility to false.
>   Start your new Schema Registry instances with these configs.

Comment: Thanks for the info Gwen. My use case is not multi-DC. I just need to make my current running Schema Registry to handle failover by making it cluster (master-slaves).  I have only once DC & once Kafka cluster.

Comment: Ah, in that case, just install two schema registry servers and point them to the same zookeeper path. One of them will become leader and the other a follower automatically. You can see the current leader in /<schema.registry.zk.namespace>/schema_registry_master path in ZooKeeper

Comment: Thanks Gwen. Also please let me know how can I use schema registry service. Currently I am using like http://<registry-server-hostname>:port. Now after adding additional server how can i point to a common name while using service ?

Comment: @GwenShapira Assuming that I have two instances of Schema Registry up and running, one listening on `8081`, and another listening on `18081`; Do both of them accept `GET` requests? Although I am able to get a response when calling `kafka-host:8081/subjects`, I am not able to get a response for `kafka-host:18081/subjects`. Is this a normal behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

I used confluent schema-registry docker [image](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#schema-registry-configuration) to form the cluster.

```
docker run --restart always -d -p 8081:8081 --name=schema-registry-1 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry-1 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.2.1-1

docker run --restart always -d -p 8081:8081 --name=schema-registry-2 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry-2 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.2.1-1

docker run --restart always -d -p 8081:8081 --name=schema-registry-3 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry-3 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.2.1-1
```

Once this is up and running I verified if schema-registry cluster is formed and if its leader election is successful, by checking the zookeeper contents.

```
$ docker exec -it zookeeper bash
# /usr/bin/zookeeper-shell localhost:2181
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /
[schema_registry, cluster, controller, brokers, zookeeper, admin, isr_change_notification, log_dir_event_notification, controller_epoch, kafka-manager, CruiseControlBrokerList, consumers, latest_producer_id_block, config]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] ls /schema_registry
[schema_registry_master, schema_id_counter]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 4] get /schema_registry/schema_registry_master
{"host":"schema-registry-1","port":8081,"master_eligibility":true,"scheme":"http","version":1}
#
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put this in the connect-avro-distributed.properties to use multi schema registry：

```
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://node1:8081,http://node2:8081
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://node1:8081,http://node2:8081
```

Hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Hmm, is this truly legit. Because, what if you want to add new connect with new schema registry and etc. You would need to add new schema-url on every connect which means - you would need to restart every single connect which ofc can be catastrophic. Isn't that what you want to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to mention `master.eligibility=true` in all the nodes.